# Return "SELECT" sql command

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to make my form contain all the rows of a table of a Postgres database, for this I am using a DataGridView with 2 columns (name and password), and searching the database for the values. But I'm new to this, and i don't know how to take db data and put it in the DataGrid.

Basically I wanted to make the same pgAdmin visual table be shown in my C# application form.

Postgre.cs:

```
public static NpgsqlDataReader listUsers()
        {
            string sqlCommand = "SELECT name, senha FROM users";
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlCommand, Connect());

            NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            return reader;
        }
```

frmAdmin:

```
public partial class frmAdmin : Form
    {
        public frmAdmin()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Postgre.listUsers();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I took part of the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053791/how-to-get-the-value-of-selected-row-from-postgresql-in-c)

I think it should work, but when I run I get a `System.StackOverflowException`.

Edit1: I solved the overflow problem, but now the problem is "System.NullReferenceException", in the `dataGridView1.DataSource = Postgre.listUsers()`. I updated the code.

Comment: Do you know at which line you are getting the exception?  What does `Connect()` do?  Does it return the correct data type/structure?

Comment: This doesn't seem C, maybe C#?

Comment: @DavidRanieri [that's C#](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) indeed.

Comment: My guess is that you call this method in the constructor of `frmAdmin`, so you create a new form, which calls this method, which creates a new form, which calls this method, etc. Either that or you have a property that's returning itself in the getter.

Comment: I updated the code question

Comment: @richyen `Connect()` connect the code with the Postgre server. Returns a "NpgsqlDataReader" var. Exception now in the `dataGridView1.DataSource` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

dataGridView1.DataSource = reader;

Comment: i make this, and i receive "System.NullReferenceException" in `dataGridView1.DataSource = Postgre.listUsers()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved, how? i don't know, but i solved:

Postgre.cs:

```
public static DataTable listUsers()
        {
            string sqlCommand = "SELECT name, senha FROM users";
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(new NpgsqlCommand(sqlCommand, Connect()));

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
```

and...
frmAdmin.cs:

```
private void listUsersGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Postgre.listUsers();
        }
```

"ListUsersGrid" is executed with the "Enter" event on tabControl1.
i don't know how i solved it so i won't do any giant text explaining every thing in the code.